# HP DeskJet 1000 J110 printer won't print

Tags: 10.04, drivers, printing, hp

I installed the `ppa:hplip-isv/ppa` for a HP DeskJet 1000 J110 printer.

hp print drivers installed but...printer still won't print.

Why?

Comment: what ppa? and what printer?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hplip-isv/ppa for a HP DeskJet 1000 J110 printer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Connect your printer to your computer and go to **System > Administration > Printing**

Remove the printer and install the hp software:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui -y
```

Configure your printer

```
sudo hp-setup
```

Comment: Print icon does not work and neither do any of my synaptic programs. Update Manager, Ubuntu Software Center, and Print make a brief appearance on screen and then disappear without doing anything.